# Child element expanding parent's width despite negative margin and overflow.

Tags: html, css, overflow, fixed-width, margin

I'm trying to make a centered page with a fixed width containing a single element expanding above these borders (as Design element). 
In wide viewports it works as expected, but when the window gets smaller than the width of that element it will cut off the left side but will make the page scroll to view the right protrusion.

Is there a way to have both sides equally cut off in small viewports?

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #CCC; /*just for better viewing */
  padding: 20px 0;  /*just for better viewing */
}
#navigation {
  position: relative;
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0 -25px;
  text-indent: 25px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);  /*just for better viewing */
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="navigation">
    Some Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the `#wrapper` supposed to be centered? Also, if our screen width is less than 950px, how do you want to handle that?  On the smaller screens, do you want the left/right nav bar overhangs?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the margin:0 auto; within the #wrapper, so yes it's supposed to be centered. For a screen <950px I would like the overhanging 25px on each side to be "ignored" and start scrolling when it's less than 900px wide.

Comment: For screens less than 900px, what do you mean by "start scrolling when it's less than 900px wide"? Please explain.

Comment: The wrapper should always be at a min-width of 900, so all content will stay as it is. But it shouldn't be possible to scroll further than the edges of the wrapper. In the current code snippet that works with the left side but not with the right.

Answer (score 0):

For the margin, use a percentage instead of px for mobile devices, so it fits the viewport

```
#wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 110%; /* Change this percentage for more accurate width */
overflow: visible;
background: #CCC; /*just for better viewing */
padding: 20px 0;  /*just for better viewing */
}
#navigation {
position: relative;
width: 950px;
margin: 0 -25px;
text-indent: 25px;
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);  /*just for better viewing */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="navigation">
   Some Content
 </div>
</div>
```

Also, change the wrapper width to a percentage, if you want that to fit.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely incorporate the percentage-model in the mobile CSS.
Although I'm still a bit troubled with the normal CSS, as it's a pixel-perfect Layout and I can't just change that (due to a fixed header-image-size of 900px).

Answer (score 0):

A key here may be to remove the `navbar` from the `wrapper` and give it a negative top margin and also change the overflow of your body to hidden such as in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pqLo4xm/2/)

Comment: Probably cleaner code, but unfortunately the Problem remains. 
I don't understand why the viewport doesn't consider the negative margin on the right and always expands to 925px instead of cutting it off like it does on the left side.

Comment: If you are willing to leave the overhang you could add an additional wrapper with a width equal to the larger of the two elements https://jsfiddle.net/xpu76mav/

Comment: That is actually my workaround for now (I simply set a min-width for the body).
But of course it would be nicer not to have the overhang on either side.

Comment: You may want to create a media query to handle this scenario by tweaking your css.